# How can I determine the level of clouds of operational significance in METAR?

Tags: weather, metar, meteorology

Considering that

Minimum sector altitude of the airport = 10500 feet

Airport elevation from [MSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_level) = 2500 feet

What is the level of clouds of operational significance in [METAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/METAR) for this airport? Should we subtract the airport’s elevation from [MSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_safe_altitude#FAA_definition)?

For more explanation

If we have a broken altostratus clouds at 9000 feet height relative to the ground, which coding is correct?

1- …..7000 -RA BKN090…

2- …..7000 -RA NSC…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Codes used:

- `NSC`: Nil significant cloud
- `CAVOK`: [Ceiling and visibility ok](https://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/CAVOK)
- `BRK`: Broken (5 to 7 [oktas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okta))

Abbreviations used:

- WMO: [World meteorological organization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Meteorological_Organization)
- METAR: [Meteorological aerodrome report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/METAR)
- AAL: [Above aerodrome level](https://skybrary.aero/sites/default/files/bookshelf/3298.pdf)
- AMSL: [Above mean sea level](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Above_mean_sea_level)
- MSA: [Minimum sector altitude](https://www.skybrary.aero/articles/minimum-sector-altitude-msa)
- CB: [Cumulonimbus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulonimbus_cloud)
- TCU: [Towering cumulus congestus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulus_congestus_cloud)

---

In your case:

- Broken [altostratus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altocumulus_cloud) layer at 9,000 ft AAL.

The cloud group is usually composed of two parts, `NNNhhh`:

- `NNN`: Cloud cover = `BRK`
- `hhh`: Height of the base / 100, AAL = `090`

So the default cloud group would be <s>`BRK090`</s> however, from WMO in [Aerodrome Reports and Forecasts - A Users’ Handbook to the Codes](https://library.wmo.int/viewer/30224?medianame=782_2022_edition_en_#page=1&viewer=picture&o=bookmark&n=0&q=):

> When there are no clouds below 1 500 m (5 000 ft) or below the highest minimum sector altitude, whichever is greater, no restriction to vertical visibility and the abbreviation CAVOK is not appropriate, the abbreviation NSC (Nil Significant Cloud) is used.

In your case:

- Airport: 2,500 ft AMSL.
- Cloud base at 9,000 AAL + 2,500 = 11,500 AMSL.
- Highest MSA: 10,500 ft AMSL.

Cloud base is 1,000 ft above the MSA, use `NSC` in place of <s>`BRK090`</s>.

In addition if:

- the horizontal visibility is 10 km or greater and
- there are no CB/TCU at any altitude,

`CAVOK` is usable in place of visibility, present weather and cloud groups.